# Javascript loop time complexity

Tags: javascript

When looping an array, people often use a simple method like below.

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

My question is if `array[i]` is O(1) operation or not.

For example, when `i` is 3, does javascript get the number immediately OR count from 0 to 3 again?

Comment: Time complexity is used for loops and not for operations. So `O()` will be evaluated for `for` and not for lookup `array[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `array[i]` is O(1). However you do it `N` times, which makes the entire loop O(n).

Comment: This could be a comment but oddly answers question as well. Simple and to the point

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, it is O(1).

Because it takes a single step to access an item of an array via its index, or add/remove an item at the end of an array, the complexity for accessing, pushing, or popping a value in an array is O(1).

ref: [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-complexity-of-simple-algorithms-and-data-structures-in-javascript-11e25b29de1e/#:%7E:text=Because%20it%20takes%20a%20single,complexity%20of%20O(n).)

Answer (score 0):

Should be O(1) you can read it at here
[javascript array complexity](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-complexity-of-simple-algorithms-and-data-structures-in-javascript-11e25b29de1e/#:%7E:text=Arrays,array%20is%20O(1).)